# Flatpickr: Submit form OnChange date

Tags: flatpickr

I try to use OnChange to send the selected date to my form in order to reload my page with the selected date in URL parameter but I don't find how to do this.

Previously I used jQuery datepicker and it was pretty simple.

```
<form id="form" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="basicDate" placeholder="Please select Date Time" data-input>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
  <script>
 $("#basicDate").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
});
 </script>
```

previously, using jQuery date picker:

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='formId'>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       onSelect : function (dateText, inst) {
          $('#formId').submit(); // <-- SUBMIT
  }});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit form when input has been changed and also check input is not blank.
Here is code for that :

```
<form id="form" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="basicDate" placeholder="Please select Date Time" data-input>
</form>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.1/flatpickr.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#basicDate").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
});
});
$(document).on('change','#basicDate',function(){

    if($('#basicDate').val() != ''){
       $('#form').submit();
}
});
```

Comment: Please add name="basicDate" in your input element in your form.